# Crontab Issues no workarounds for my problem

Tags: syntax, cron

[My Terminal Image Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deU52.png)

Unable to get my Crontab to work. I press enter and it won't run. I put my path to my Visual Studio code: ( * 2 * * * /Users/laughinfm/Desktop/Clock Automation/Clock Automation.py )

Comment: Not working like expected. Im trying to do https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5bTkiV_Aadc&t=653s at timestamp 9:43 . My path won't work and my crontab terminal does nothing.

Comment: I need help with this still. I input into terminal: * * * * * python /Users/ryanbert/Desktop/zon_Automation/import_schedule_test.py  It till no work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try typing   `quit()`

or press `control-c` to break

or simply open a new window or quit the application

Comment: My code in visual studio still wont run every minute

Comment: Sorry, I can't really help. I usually use some kernel or Atom editor to code, though.